# Delegate and thread issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, delegates

I have a thread which has a Procedure with this loop:

```
Private Sub SendFiles()
  For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView_Monitor.Items

     ' do something...

  Next Item
End Sub
```

That causes a cross-thread operation error when trying to read the ***Items*** collection of the **ListView_Monitor**

I've tried to write the correct delegate to avoid that error but I'm missing something and does not work my delegate, so for now I set ***CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls*** to ***False***.

Someone can show me how would be the correct delegate for the operation I need?

Comment: Just don't use control properties in a worker thread.  And especially never use CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls.  You just don't have to, create a List from the ListView and pass that to the thread.  And you should already have one anyway, separate the view from the model.

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks for the advice/council

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mess about with a UI component on a non-UI thread, I would advise using `Invoke` to force your code to run on the UI thread e.g.

```
ListView_Monitor.Invoke(Sub()
    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView_Monitor.Items
        ' do something...
    Next Item
End Sub)
```

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you did, I've tried to paste it as is inside my Sub but does not work, Before Invoke I don't need to specify a new delegate to read the data?

Comment: @ElektroHacker Are you getting some sort of compiler error? I am forcing the code to run on the UI thread via [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx). In my example I am using an anonymous one, I may have the syntax wrong I am not at a machine ATM to verify (more of a C# fan!), however, if you prefer you can declare a named delegate if you'd prefer and pass instead.

Comment: It does not throw any error just does not work, does not happens anything so maybe I'm having syntax error too, but anyways like how you explain me what your code does then I need to say that the reason why I'm using a subprocess is because I don't want to run that procedure on the main thread (the UI thread), I want to run it in a separate thread, not to force it into the main thread, so I need a delegate to read the listview created in the UI thread, then I think your solution can't help me, but I appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: "*I don't want to run that procedure on the main thread (the UI thread)*" - yes you do, otherwise it won't work or you will get very unexpected behaviour. The reason you update the control on the UI thread is because that's the same thread the control is running on, trying to update it on a different thread leads to cross-threading exceptions.

Comment: "trying to update it on a different thread leads to cross-threading exceptions", of course I'm trying to say that's the reason why I need a delegate to read the control from a sub-thread like I saw in all threads examples over the web, but all examples I've seen are delegates to set a property value, I don't know the way to use a delegate to "read" the control like I need. Do you understand me?

Comment: @ElektroHacker yes what you are asking is to *read* the control property from 1 thread but update in another. However, you seem to be missing the point - **don't mess about with UI components in a non-UI thread**.

Comment: @ElektroHacker As Hans pointed out, you need to separate your view from your model.  In other words, don't *store* your data only in your controls.  Use the controls as a way of *displaying* the data that you actually have *stored* somewhere else.  That way, in the thread, you can just work with your data model (the non-ui data structure in memory), and not ever have to deal with any of the controls.  Then, if the thread modifies the data, you can then update the controls to reflect those changes, but that obviously has to be done from the UI thread.

Comment: @Steven Doggart you will mean for example to store the listview items collection in a type container for example in a new List(Of Listviewitem) inside a Variable and then use that variable in the other threads to get the desired info instead reading directly the control? that is a better practice than what I was trying to do? EDIT: Ok yes I seen now the Hans Passant comment, thankyou all